# MySQL INSERT using SELECT with extra variables

Tags: mysql, variables

How can I `INSERT` a row using `SELECT` from an other table including a variable(s) for a following query which doesn't match the target row because of the columns count?

```
INSERT INTO posts(
    post_id,
    post_version_id
)
SELECT
    post_versions.post_id AS post_id,
    post_versions.post_version_id AS post_version_id,
    @post_id_current := post_versions.post_id
FROM
    post_versions
LEFT JOIN posts ON posts.post_version_id = post_versions.post_version_id
WHERE
    posts.post_id = 9
ORDER BY
    post_versions.post_version ASC
LIMIT 1
```

... second query using `@post_id_current`

```
SELECT @post_id_current
```

Comment: Your select query can only have two result columns. So get rid of the sessinvariable, or build a select that only gives two cloumns around your sekect

Comment: You should be able to make that session variable assignment in the first field selection, i.e. `@post_id_current := post_versions.post_id AS post_id`

Comment: You can set the var direct line: SELECT

Comment: Ups, select @post_if_current :=